# Excel Solver : Non linear least squares equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, excel, math

I am working on a forms application that reports based on observed data. Prior to development of the application, Excel spreadsheets were used along side excel solver to do non-linear least squares regression. Ive been out of University for a while, and it is possible for me to write one eventually, I doubt the client wants to wait for several months while I come up with a suitable replacement for excel's sovler.

So my question is this; Is there a C# equivalent of the Excel solver's non-linear least squares regression function? I have observed data and some initial guesses based on the observed data, so input isnt an issue. Hell, even the name of the equation used would be a good starting point.

Ive taken a look at alglib but im not sure which one would be appropriate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't work with this sort of thing, but does Microsoft Solver Foundation address your needs? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524512(v=VS.93).aspx

Comment: The Excel help says "The Microsoft Office Excel Solver tool uses the Generalized Reduced Gradient (GRG2) nonlinear optimization code, which was developed by Leon Lasdon, University of Texas at Austin, and Alan Waren, Cleveland State University". I don't think there's anything built in to the .NET Framework to do this.

Comment: What kind of non-linearity are we talking about? Is there a suitable transform to make it linear?

Comment: The observational data is supposed to fit a cosine wave, but im not entirely sure its possible to transform a cosine function to a linear equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up biting the bullet and going with alglib. The lsfit package did eventually do what I wanted, though it took me pretty darn long since its not really readable by a non mathematician.

Ill keep this here so that anyone that has the same problem can find this.

Comment: could you share your example code using alglib please?  We are needing to do a non-negative least squares and can't find any help in the alglib docs!

Comment: I can try to find it. This was quite a while ago. I havent worked on it since I figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the [MathDotNet](http://www.mathdotnet.com/downloads/Iridium-2008-8-16-470.ashx?From=IridiumCurrentRelease) Iridium library.

Here is a c# class example:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;

namespace StackOverflow.Examples
{
public class PolynomialRegression
{
    readonly Vector _xData;
    readonly Vector _yData;
    readonly Vector _coef;
    readonly int _order;

    public PolynomialRegression(Vector xData, Vector yData, int order)
    {
        if (xData.Length != yData.Length)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }
        _xData = xData;
        _yData = yData;
        _order = order;
        var n = xData.Length;
        var a = new Matrix(n, order + 1);
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            a.SetRowVector(VandermondeRow(xData[i]), i);

        // Least Squares |y=A(x)*c| ...  tr(A)*y = tr(A)*A*c  ...  inv(tr(A)*A)*tr(A)*y = c
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares
        var at = Matrix.Transpose(a);
        var y2 = new Matrix(yData, n);
        _coef = (at * a).Solve(at * y2).GetColumnVector(0);
    }

    Vector VandermondeRow(double x)
    {
        var row = new double[_order + 1];
        for (var i = 0; i <= _order; i++)
            row[i] = Math.Pow(x, i);
        return new Vector(row);
    }

    public double Fit(double x)
    {
        return Vector.ScalarProduct(VandermondeRow(x), _coef);
    }

    public int Order { get { return _order; } }
    public Vector Coefficients { get { return _coef; } }
    public Vector XData { get { return _xData; } }
    public Vector YData { get { return _yData; } }
}
}
```

And here is an example usage:

```
 var xVector = new Vector(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
 var yVector = new Vector(new double[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 });
 var order = 2;
 _poly = new PolynomialRegression(xVector, yVector, order);
```

Comment: I took a look at the documentation on their website, it doesnt look like they have a non-linear least squares method. Ill keep this link though, could come in handy later.

Answer (score 2):

One option you have is to simply use Excel from your C# program. This way the computation is done by Excel and your program can do anything that Excel can do. See [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084)

Another option is to use one of the many available mathematics libraries, as pointed out by Michael. There are many libraries available. Of course you will want to verify that the answers that you get match Excel ;-)

Comment: The question is, can I call excel solver from visual studio? Im pretty sure its not standard in versions of excel.

Comment: John S: Of course the Excel solver (+Excel) needs to be installed on the user's computer for this to work. I believe you should have no problems assuming that prerequisite is met.

Comment: That is true, but with the Excel solver there is alot of user input required for it to function. Ill give this a shot over the holiday and hopefully it will work.